# How properly initialize JBoss Weld in Java SE without using org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain#main?

Tags: java, javafx-2, jboss-weld

I'm working on a JavaFX 2 project and the application must be launched using another main method (com.javafx.main.Main according to the generated JAR manifest). According to the official Weld [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5406) the bootstrapping involves launching the application via `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain` which is impossible to do in my (edge) case... However, looking at the source, the `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain#main` method only has one line of code in it:

```
new StartMain(args).go();
```

So, I figured I'll just use that particular line of code in my application at the "right time" (alternatively, I could've just called StartMain.main(args) from within my app). But I'm not confident if there are any repercussions to doing this. Does anyone know of a better way of accomplishing this?

Versions:

JavaFX 2.0.2

Weld 2.0.0.Alpha1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grab](http://seamframework.org/Weld/WeldDistributionDownloads) at least 1.1.3 Final version of Weld and initialize your container via the main Weld class, as versus using StartMain:

```
WeldContainer weld = new Weld().initialize();
```

Comment: that's part of what happens in StartMain#go. It also adds a shutdown hook and sets the command line arguments.